# Passing multiple flags to an intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this activity that lists some information which I provide a refresh button for. The way I'm refreshing it (probably not the best way by any means) is just launching the activity all over again. To make the back stack work the way I need it to I need to pass in the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag to the intent and it works fine. But to give the illusion that the information is refreshing the information within the activity and not completely relaunching it, I also need to add the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION`. So far, I haven't been able to get these two flags to work together. I've tried the following methods:

```
theIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION+Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
theIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

theIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
theIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Clear top works correctly for all of them but the animation is still there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 60):

Use operator | to set multiple flags

```
theIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: @100Kg,lances
 try applying `<style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
 </style>`

to your activity in manifest:

`<activity 
android:name="com.me.myproject.MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme"
            />`

Comment: Why it has to be or instead of and.
How does this work?

Answer (score 42):

For folks that may be making an Android app in Kotlin

```
coolIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I was using Kotlin in that part...

Comment: How does this work?
It seems like it should be and, doesn't it?

Comment: because it's a logical `or` operation, It's not same as `||`.   
It's `or` because you want to sum the bits (to end up with `1`s if either is 1)

Answer (score 10):

Use `addFlags()` so that you can add multiple number of Flags to Intent.

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 3):

You might try using

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

immediately after calling startActivity();

Comment: I used but now it show black screen first and then target one.